# ImageResizer Diagnotics plugin (resizer.debug)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, debugging

*hello* **StackOverflow**

i have a **question**

**can you tell me what is resizer? debug and what is the risk of this file on the server I have found this log on the server what is the risk? and why this log here?
can you tell me about this resizer.debug  thank you**

**

````
Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.LicenseDisplay
ImageResizer.Plugins.EPiServerBlobReader.EPiServerBlobReaderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]

Accepted querystring keys:

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key OutputCache)
Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync, 

                    
System.Xml                               File: 4.8.3761.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.3761.0                     
System.Core                              File: 4.8.4330.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.4330.0                     
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure File: 1.0.30709.0 (1.0.0.0)     Informational: 1.0.2-30709                    
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Base File: 1.0.30709.0 (1.0.0.0)     Informational: 1.0.2-30709                    
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication File: 1.0.3.0 (1.0.3.0)         Informational:                                
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault                 File: 2.3.2.0 (2.0.0.0)         Informational: 2.3.2                          
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime             File: 2.3.20.0 (2.0.0.0)        Informational: 2.3.20                         
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure       File: 3.3.7.0 (3.0.0.0)         Informational: 3.3.7                          
Newtonsoft.Json                          File: 12.0.3.23909 (12.0.0.0)   Informational: 12.0.3+7c3d7f8da7e35dde8fa74188b0decff70f8f10e3  
System.Net.Http                          File: 4.8.3761.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.3761.0                     
System.Net.Http.WebRequest               File: 4.8.3761.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.3761.0                     
System.Runtime.Serialization             File: 4.8.4261.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.4261.0                     
SMDiagnostics                            File: 4.8.4261.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.4261.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Internals            File: 4.8.4261.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.4261.0                     
System.Numerics                          File: 4.8.3761.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.3761.0                     
System.Data                              File: 4.8.4290.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.8.4290.0                     
Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots      File: 1.1.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
Microsoft.JScript                        File: 14.8.3761.0 (10.0.0.0)    Informational: 14.8.3761.0                    
System.Web.WebPages                      File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.Mvc                           File: 5.2.30128.0 (5.2.3.0)     Informational: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  

```   **
````

Answer (score 0):

Image Resizer provides a set of tools for configuring Image properties.

`resizer.debug` or `resizer.debug.ashx` helps you to know the configuration and plugin installation issues which provides a ImageResizer’s self-diagnostics page. If your local website is running at `http://localhost:5000/`, then you should browse to `http://localhost:5000/resizer.debug.ashx` to access it.

For more Information, you can check this [TroubleShooting page](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4#troubleshooting%20section).